# How can I prevent integer value from going negative

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I am working in an app in which I have option to choose quantity number for selected product by default quantity is set to 1 while increasing and decreasing quantity I am able to go to negative numbers like -1 ,-2,-3...
How do I restrict quantity from going negative.

this my code for reducing quantity value

```
setState(() {
  itemCount = itemCount - 1;
  price = itemCount - price;
});
```

Comment: `if (itemCount > 0) itemCount--;`

Comment: this works, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an if check as @Mobina said:

```
if (itemCount > 0) price = itemCount - price;
```

Or use the `max` function from the math library:

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final itemCount = 1;
  final price = max(0, itemCount - 5);
}
```